# An easy to use tool for backuping/mirroring Debian server

Tags: linux, debian, backup

I have VDS with Debian server and ISPManager and now I'm looking for solution which can help me to backup/restore/clone whole server as I can backup my Windows drives with Acronis (for example).

I spent a lot of time trying tools like Clonezilla. But all I find are not user-friendly for me.

Can anyone suggest me a tool for backuping/mirroring Debian server **which is easy to use**?

***Update***: It would be better if it has web-interface or client for Windows.

Comment: "Like Clonezilla" - care to share which ones, what you don't like about them, and what you're looking for? For example, Bacula is pretty popular. You might need to define "easy to use" as one persons idea of easy is different to another.

Comment: @Mark Henderson, I don't like Clonezilla because it needs cd-drive or server replacement.
I looked into this list: http://wiki.debian.org/BackupAndRecovery. Things I tried from it aren't to easy to use (just look at [BackupPC](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianEdu/HowTo/BackupPC) setup) and don't have GUI so I can't see what work was done, what settings are there, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use this as `root`:

```
rsync -auvz --numeric-ids -e ssh root@1.2.3.4:/ ./backup/
```

Just run this on a local linux machine, and you're done. Flip the last two parameters around to restore. One major advantage of this is after you make a full initial copy, further copies *only copy the difference* so are extremely fast. If you want to keep rotated backups, take a look at [rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/).